# Understanding child pages hierarchy in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet, private

I will sum the logic through 4 easy questions:

1. Can/should private pages have public child pages? (it seems private pages are using other site or context for any group/user)
2. Can/should public pages have private child pages?
3. Can/should hidden pages have non-hidden child pages?
4. Can/should a page which certain user is not allowed to VIEW have a child page which certain user is allowed to see?

Does some of the previous scenarios change parent page's behavior? I mean maybe allowing you rights to a child page makes you automatically authorized to see parent page.

Furthermore, what is the difference between **hidden** and **non-hidde**n pages? I can browse both through links!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your questions (for Liferay 6.1, may differ for earlier versions):

1. Private pages can only have private child pages
2. Public pages can only have public child pages but the children can
   be hidden (so they don't appear in the navigation but can be
   accessed directly by the URL)
3. They can, but they also won't appear in the navigation unless
   you've changed your theme so that they do
4. Yes it can, and again it's up to you and whether you want to
   theme to have that restriction or not

Parent page behaviour is not affected by child page settings.

**Hidden page**: Pages that are hidden from the navigation but can be accessed directly via links or typing in their URL

**Non-Hidden pages**: Can be seen in the navigation, and can accessed in the same way as hidden pages.

**Private pages**: Can only be accessed by authenticated members of the community that they belong to. They are effectively gated pages so hidden from public viewing without having to set the page permissions for Guest users.

I hope this answers all your questions.

~~ EDIT ~~

As Julien Lafont as mentioned below: Hidden pages are visible in the search portlet. If you want to hide them from a particular group of users, use permissions. Thanks Julien.

Comment: Awesome, clear and fast answer, I would give you 10 checks if I could

Comment: About hidden page, use with caution because they will be visible in the Search portlet.

Comment: Thanks Julien, I've added that info to my answer to make it clear.

Comment: How can I access this hidden pages in lifery theme?? nav_items??